# How to recover from Docker Error Illegal Instruction on Raspberry Pi 3B

Tags: docker, docker-compose, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3

I am running into the following error when starting up containers on my Raspberry Pi 3B on Raspbian Buster:

```
docker: Error response from daemon: : signal: illegal instruction (core dumped): unknown.
ERRO[0001] error waiting for container: context canceled
```

Lately I've been maxing out resources on the Raspberry Pi 3B (looking into upgrading but I don't want to stop selfhosting in the meantime), so sometimes containers are exiting error status due to lack of resources.

Containers have been working fine when restarting until this morning. This morning I've been getting the above illegal instruction error. This happens with all containers I have, `docker` and `docker-compose`, and even just when running `docker run hello-world` using dockers hello-world example container. There hasn't been any updates run in a week, so new updates likely wouldn't be the problem (namely with `docker-ce`, `raspberrypi-kernal` which have cause conflicts in the past but were quickly resolved).

I've tried rebooting, removing and installing `docker-ce`, removing all containers, removing all networks, removing images, and restarting the Docker Service.

When running something like `docker-compose --verbose up -d lidarr`, the illegal instruction error always seems to occur around connecting to the network. Towards the end of the output is below, with some of the repetition removed:

```
...
...

compose.cli.verbose_proxy.proxy_callable: docker create_container <- (environment=['PUID=1000', 'PGID=1000', 'TZ=America/New_York'], image='linuxserver/lidarr:latest', ports=[('8686', 'tcp')], volumes={'/music': {}, '/config': {}, '/downloads': {}}, name='pi_lidarr_1', detach=True, labels={'com.docker.compose.project': 'pi', 'com.docker.compose.service': 'lidarr', 'com.docker.compose.oneoff': 'False', 'com.docker.compose.project.working_dir': '/home/pi', 'com.docker.compose.project.config_files': 'docker-compose.yml', 'com.docker.compose.container-number': '1', 'com.docker.compose.version': '1.29.2', 'com.docker.compose.config-hash': '1ee750c8b41eee12fce59c62e06cdf73a46c7177c028d758de86977788a63b1e'}, host_config={'NetworkMode': 'pi_default', 'RestartPolicy': {'Name': 'unless-stopped', 'MaximumRetryCount': 0}, 'VolumesFrom': [], 'Binds': ['/path/to/music:/music:rw', '/path/to/config:/config:rw', '/path/to/downloads:/downloads:rw'], 'PortBindings': {'8686/tcp': [{'HostIp': '', 'HostPort': '8686'}]}, 'Links': [], 'LogConfig': {'Type': '', 'Config': {}}}, networking_config={'EndpointsConfig': {'pi_default': {'Aliases': ['lidarr'], 'IPAMConfig': {}}}})
compose.parallel.feed_queue: Pending: set()
compose.parallel.feed_queue: Pending: set()
...
...
compose.parallel.feed_queue: Pending: set()
compose.parallel.feed_queue: Pending: set()
compose.cli.verbose_proxy.proxy_callable: docker create_container -> {'Id': 'c33e4f4808dac0c794f3806176ad73cafddf10a7088e62181fcf79065db6cb4f',
 'Warnings': []}
compose.cli.verbose_proxy.proxy_callable: docker inspect_container <- ('c33e4f4808dac0c794f3806176ad73cafddf10a7088e62181fcf79065db6cb4f')
compose.parallel.feed_queue: Pending: set()
compose.cli.verbose_proxy.proxy_callable: docker inspect_container -> {'AppArmorProfile': '',
 'Args': [],
 'Config': {'AttachStderr': False,
            'AttachStdin': False,
            'AttachStdout': False,
            'Cmd': None,
            'Domainname': '',
            'Entrypoint': ['/init'],
            'Env': ['PUID=1000',
                    'PGID=1000',
...
compose.cli.verbose_proxy.proxy_callable: docker disconnect_container_from_network <- ('c33e4f4808dac0c794f3806176ad73cafddf10a7088e62181fcf79065db6cb4f', 'pi_default')
compose.parallel.feed_queue: Pending: set()
compose.cli.verbose_proxy.proxy_callable: docker disconnect_container_from_network -> None
compose.cli.verbose_proxy.proxy_callable: docker connect_container_to_network <- ('c33e4f4808dac0c794f3806176ad73cafddf10a7088e62181fcf79065db6cb4f', 'pi_default', aliases=['lidarr', 'c33e4f4808da'], ipv4_address=None, ipv6_address=None, links=[], link_local_ips=None)
compose.parallel.feed_queue: Pending: set()
compose.parallel.feed_queue: Pending: set()
compose.parallel.feed_queue: Pending: set()
compose.parallel.feed_queue: Pending: set()
compose.cli.verbose_proxy.proxy_callable: docker connect_container_to_network -> None
compose.cli.verbose_proxy.proxy_callable: docker start <- ('c33e4f4808dac0c794f3806176ad73cafddf10a7088e62181fcf79065db6cb4f')
compose.parallel.feed_queue: Pending: set()
compose.parallel.feed_queue: Pending: set()
...
...
compose.parallel.feed_queue: Pending: set()
compose.parallel.feed_queue: Pending: set()
Creating pi_lidarr_1 ... error
compose.parallel.feed_queue: Pending: set()

ERROR: for pi_lidarr_1  Cannot start service lidarr: : signal: illegal instruction (core dumped): unknown
compose.parallel.parallel_execute_iter: Failed: <Service: lidarr>
compose.parallel.feed_queue: Pending: set()

ERROR: for lidarr  Cannot start service lidarr: : signal: illegal instruction (core dumped): unknown
ERROR: compose.cli.main.exit_with_metrics: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.
```

For system info, `uname -a` outputs:

```
Linux raspberrypi 5.10.63-v7+ #1496 SMP Wed Dec 1 15:58:11 GMT 2021 armv7l GNU/Linux
```

`docker-compose version` outputs:

```
docker-compose version 1.29.2, build unknown
docker-py version: 5.0.0
CPython version: 3.7.3
OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.1.1d  10 Sep 2019
```

`docker --version` outputs:

```
Docker version 20.10.12, build e91ed57
```

`docker info` displays:

```
Client:
 Context:    default
 Debug Mode: false
 Plugins:
  app: Docker App (Docker Inc., v0.9.1-beta3)
  buildx: Docker Buildx (Docker Inc., v0.7.1-docker)

Server:
 Containers: 1
  Running: 0
  Paused: 0
  Stopped: 1
 Images: 7
 Server Version: 20.10.12
 Storage Driver: overlay2
  Backing Filesystem: extfs
  Supports d_type: true
  Native Overlay Diff: true
  userxattr: false
 Logging Driver: json-file
 Cgroup Driver: cgroupfs
 Cgroup Version: 1
 Plugins:
  Volume: local
  Network: bridge host ipvlan macvlan null overlay
  Log: awslogs fluentd gcplogs gelf journald json-file local logentries splunk syslog
 Swarm: inactive
 Runtimes: io.containerd.runc.v2 io.containerd.runtime.v1.linux runc
 Default Runtime: runc
 Init Binary: docker-init
 containerd version: 7b11cfaabd73bb80907dd23182b9347b4245eb5d
 runc version: v1.0.2-0-g52b36a2
 init version: de40ad0
 Security Options:
  seccomp
   Profile: default
 Kernel Version: 5.10.63-v7+
 Operating System: Raspbian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)
 OSType: linux
 Architecture: armv7l
 CPUs: 4
 Total Memory: 923.2MiB
 Name: raspberrypi
 ID: EHO6:EVEP:2WCL:G5HM:S4TO:BOFX:WXTM:GXBA:X5Z6:6YYI:YVMW:QGEZ
 Docker Root Dir: /var/lib/docker
 Debug Mode: false
 Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
 Labels:
 Experimental: false
 Insecure Registries:
  127.0.0.0/8
 Live Restore Enabled: false

WARNING: No memory limit support
WARNING: No swap limit support
WARNING: No kernel memory TCP limit support
WARNING: No oom kill disable support
WARNING: No blkio throttle.read_bps_device support
WARNING: No blkio throttle.write_bps_device support
WARNING: No blkio throttle.read_iops_device support
WARNING: No blkio throttle.write_iops_device support
```

Containers, to name a few, that are "causing" the illegal instruction error:

- FireFlyiii (fireflyiii/core:latest, image ID 1da032b42837 from 2 weeks ago)
- MariaDB (yobasystems/apline-mariadb:10.4.15, image ID 52efb22cde7e from 16 weeks ago)
- Lidarr (linuxserver/lidarr:latest, image ID b21ad10fe43c from 12 days ago)
- hello-world (hello-world:latest, image ID 1ec996c686eb from 4 months ago)

Update: I checked Journalctl for docker entries after trying to `docker run hello-world` and found:

```
Feb 26 13:08:25 raspberrypi dockerd[4602]: time="2022-02-26T13:08:25.253390090-05:00" level=error msg="stream copy error: reading from a closed fifo"
Feb 26 13:08:25 raspberrypi dockerd[4602]: time="2022-02-26T13:08:25.253526860-05:00" level=error msg="stream copy error: reading from a closed fifo"
Feb 26 13:08:26 raspberrypi dockerd[4602]: time="2022-02-26T13:08:26.084248757-05:00" level=error msg="2caf65051f4e40260e125c398541db0969a57ff8544c4ae9010c3e859f43ba25 cleanup: failed to delete container from containerd: no such container"
Feb 26 13:08:26 raspberrypi dockerd[4602]: time="2022-02-26T13:08:26.084429642-05:00" level=error msg="Handler for POST /v1.41/containers/2caf65051f4e40260e125c398541db0969a57ff8544c4ae9010c3e859f43ba25/start returned error: : signal: illegal instruction (core dumped): unknown"
```

Does anyone know how to diagnose and/or recover from this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve this, unfortunately I won't be able to find out why this happened.

I tried removing and installing `docker-ce` and dependencies again. I wasn't able to remove due to `containerd.service` not stopping. I found it was set to always restart, which would normally make sense. I then ran `sudo systemctl disable docker containerd` and rebooted. I confirmed those services were no longer running by following journalctl output, looking for the usual restarting and core-dump errors from `docker` and `containerd`.

I ran `sudo apt remove docker-ce` and `sudo apt autoremove` again, then ran docker's `get-docker.sh` which reinstalled docker. I then ran `sudo systemctl enable docker containerd` and `sudo systemctl start docker containerd`. Docker is the same version it was before and the hello-world container and other containers of mine that wasn't previously running is now running successfully.